# Microsoft Access Web App - Sharepoint online - user permission only for the app

Tags: permissions, microsoft-access, web-application, sharepoint-2013

I want to publish a access web app (2013) with sharepoint online to the web for costumers. I don't want that the users of the app have access to the sharepoint site behind the app, neither that they can download it and edit the database in access. I tried to find a solution in several books and videos, but i couldn't find anything. Is there any way to fade out the menu bar in the top? or any other ways to give the users only a permission to see/use the app and nothing else? I use sharepoint plan E1.

Answer (score -1):

From the design in desktop access, look at the save as options for your web app. One will take away ability to edit using Ms Access.